# Using a new line escape sequence in JSON when posting to facebook from iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, escaping

I am working on an app that posts restaurant information to the user's Facebook wall.  Everything works fine, except I don't know how to insert a new line within the "description" section of the JSON code.  My relevant code is as follows:

```
FBStreamDialog* dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
dialog.userMessagePrompt = @"Enter your message:";
dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"Check out this great restaurant!\",\"href\":\"/\",\"caption\":\"%@\",\"description\":\"%@ /*NEW LINE HERE*/%@, %@ /*NEW LINE HERE*/%@\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"http://www.myhost.ca/images/image_IC_B_03.png\",\"href\":\"http://www.myhost.com/\"}]}",
                     restaurantObj.name, restaurantObj.address, restaurantObj.city, restaurantObj.provinceState, restaurantObj.phoneNumber];
dialog.actionLinks = @"[{\"text\":\"Download this app!\",\"href\":\"http://www.myhost.com/\"}]";

[dialog show];
```

I have tried to insert \n and I've tried to insert \r in the places I've marked above, but unfortunately that doesn't work.  Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use the same workaround this guy found:

[facebook c# sdk: Add/edit event with newlines in description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421890/facebook-c-sdk-add-edit-event-with-newlines-in-description)

Comment: I think you might be right in this case.  Thanks very much for showing me this!