# Message with new line character is displayed as html code

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

[image]

I am using following code to post multiline message on facebook wall/page. but it is appear as shown in image (the text are different here). here is my code.

```
string path = "/me/feed";
string token = fbLoginDialog.FacebookOAuthResult.AccessToken;

dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
messagePost.message = @"Hello guys!
How are you?
Can you help me on this?";

var fb = new FacebookClient(token);
try { var postId = fb.Post(path, messagePost); }  
catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
```

I am using Facebook.dll Version: 5.0.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using Facebook.6.0.22

download latest from here https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winforms-sample

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)?:

```
messagePost.message = "Hello guys!" + Environment.NewLine + 
                      "How are you?"+ Environment.NewLine +
                      "Can you help me on this?";
```

Environment.NewLine is a platform independent property that inserts new line char for the selected environment.

Or maybe you have a problem with your syntax and it should be:

```
messagePost.message = @"Hello guys!\r\n How are you?\r\n Can you help me on this?";
```

Comment: yes. I already tried that.. it is not working.. I also tried "<br>".. have same issue..

Comment: @HiteshRiziya, what version of SDK are you using?

Comment: Have a look at the  posts for how the message appears. https://www.facebook.com/pages/Website/103006299849148

Comment: @HiteshRiziya, Try to use the latest SDK if posslbe. It should be fixed according to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5456294/1792936

Comment: @HiteshRiziya, Sorry cannot investigate more now. If it's not fixed, I will try to take a look later today or tomorrow and let you know